# Hudson | NullPointerException while loading jobs

Tags: exception, hudson

We are using hudson version 2.0.0.
Few days back after restarting hudson, i found that some of the jobs were missing.
Found that its due to the following NPE.

```
Dec 9, 2011 11:39:34 AM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job ABC
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.Project.createTransientActions(Project.java:206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.updateTransientActions(AbstractProject.java:627)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:287)
    at hudson.model.Project.onLoad(Project.java:87)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:109)
    at hudson.model.Hudson$13.run(Hudson.java:2376)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at hudson.model.Hudson$4.runTask(Hudson.java:707)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTaskThreadPoolExecutor.java
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Upgrading to 2.1.2 didnt help. I removed all the plugins and re-installed, but in vain.
Has anybody else faced this?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: I have the same problem, looking into it right now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the problem.

To fix this issue, I had to add the line that contains <publishers/> to each config.xml file in projects that failed to load (towards the end of XML file):

```xml
  </builders>
  <buildWrappers/>
  <publishers/>
</project>
```

Somehow without this, Hudson/Jenkins barfs and hides in the corner crying.

Comment: I fixed the problem in the same way. But any idea how/why the element got removed ? I guess in my case it was because i gave discard old settings once after restarting hudson (when i installed the new email-ext plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Jobs will go missing from the dashboard when there is a parse error in the config.xml.
You can inspect these errors in **Hudson / Manage Hudson / System Log** looking for

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Could not call hudson.scm.CVSSCM.readResolve() : null :
```

It means the auto parameter migration failed and you have to edit the config.xml in the Jobs root by hand, the debug information in the log provides the offending line number. Commenting out the item usually works. Sometimes manual reconfiguring is needed.

Jobs will go missing from the history between restarts when the file build.xml is not generated in the build/<jobref> directory. If there is an exception in any plugin, it may cause the creation of this file to be skipped, and it will not show in history after a restart. Again looking in the log using **Hudson / Manage Hudson / System Log** is the quickest way to find the offending plugin. Disabling usually resolves the problem.
Please note that searching for "Missing Hudson Builds" will point to many different plugins/versions that all cause this problem. You should look in YOUR log to find what is causing the problem in YOUR installation, and only disabling the plugin that is causing YOUR problem.
A warning about "failed to generate build.xml" would save a lot of hours. I should open a bug on that.